# Port from Qt5 to Qt4 went to encoding issue on the Graphical User Interface

Tags: qt, encoding, qt4, qt5

I coded an app using Qt5 (5.3.2), then installed Qt4 (4.8.2) in the same machine (Win 7). Compiler is MinGW-4.8.2 in both cases. Source code files are in UTF-8.

Using QtCreator to build both, I got an issue related to encoding in the app Graphical User Interface of the Qt4 side. Exemplifying:

Qt5: "Configurações"

Qt4: "ConfiguraÃ§Ães"

Could someone please give a hint?

Comment: This can be caused by `QString(const char*)` constructor (e.g. `label->setText("string literal")`. This constructor uses UTF-8 encoding in Qt5 and ascii in Qt4. Replace usages of this constructor (and similar ones) with explicit conversion like `label->setText(QString::fromUtf8("string literal"))`.

Comment: Nitpicking, not US-ASCII, but whatever is set calling `QTextCodec::setCodecForCStrings`, or if it's never called, Latin1. (This should also tell you how to quickly fix this). (And also this tells you you're not compiling with `QT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII` enabled, which would prevent these things from happen.)

Comment: Great! Using  `QString CONF(QString::fromUtf8("Configurações"));` solves the problem. And if I want to use the tr(), where should I put it?

Comment: `tr(QString::fromUtf8("Configurações").toStdString().c_str())` seems to work. Any alternatives?